# Litecoinj transaction sent to unknown address

Tags: litecoin

I have used litecoinj-core-0.15 to generate a transaction to address `MD1AYTZnTtGKQToj2LTD7qLsSzrqcdXr9J`.

Litecoinj generated a [transaction](https://live.blockcypher.com/ltc/tx/1d040e92c3480348433b8a94e71eb172bb671d70434ba0546c7f32636d7d0f19) with two outputs. The first one (to `LaPJ9TfBr6E2MSRa4t1MMhFPQAue4osUn8`) corresponds to the change address. The second one is an address that I cannot understand the origin: `LQKxaEyD3XLZmbXYyVna9aoJBzLxAhNS4S`. I have tried to find it in the list of refund, change, receive_fund, and authorisation addresses of the Wallet and could not find it there.

Could someone explain from where is this address coming?

Kind regards, and thank you in advance,
António.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this by converting the addresses from base 58 to hex. What I got was this:
`MD1AYTZnTtGKQToj2LTD7qLsSzrqcdXr9J` -> `0x3237fb62589f848d3808f0b9bfe9762edabe150b93f409d315`
`LaPJ9TfBr6E2MSRa4t1MMhFPQAue4osUn8` -> `0x3037fb62589f848d3808f0b9bfe9762edabe150b93bab51bf3`

Notice that the positions from byte 1 to byte 20 are the same: `37fb...0b93`.

This is unfortunately bad news and means that the software you are using is bad.

The address that starts with M or 3 in Litecoin are pay-to-script-hash addresses (P2SH) and the software should have created P2SH outputs but it has for some reason instead created pay-to-public-key-hash outputs (P2PKH) as you can see [here](https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/ltc/main/addrs/LQKxaEyD3XLZmbXYyVna9aoJBzLxAhNS4S/full?limit=50?unspentOnly=true&includeScript=true):

`{
          "value": 15149,
          "script": "76a914a64e3a77893db78edfb3ba4abfa2106f84ba80eb88ac",
          "addresses": [
            "LaPJ9TfBr6E2MSRa4t1MMhFPQAue4osUn8"
          ],
          "script_type": "pay-to-pubkey-hash"
        },`

The funds you have sent are unfortunately lost and you should stop using this software immediately since it only seems to support P2PKH addresses and not P2SH addresses.

If it is any comfort, you are not the first one to make this mistake.

Comment: Well, not a complete surprise because litecoinj does not seem to be maintained properly. Thanks Thorkil!